# While I try to clone bitbucket repository it throws a warning and cloning is not successful. solution?

Tags: bitbucket, git-clone

Cloning into '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/flagday2'...
warning: templates not found /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates
Completed with errors, see above

The folder inside htdocs automatically removed after this.